# File upload error while editing the file using exec command

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I am using exec command to create a thumbnail of pdf.

At the time of adding code works fine:

1. File is uploading in folder
2. Added in db.

But with the following error message.

> Warning
>
> Warning: Failed to move file!
>   Error
>
> Error moving file

At the time of edit:

1. File is uploading in folder
2. Not updated in db.

And getting error message with the following error message:

> Warning
>
> Warning: Failed to move file!
>   Error
>
> Error moving file

Code:

```
$uploadPath = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR
            . '/components/com_ets_fast_track/assets/buildings/'
            . $filename;

$fileTemp = $file['tmp_name'];

if(!JFile::exists($uploadPath)){
    if (!JFile::upload($fileTemp, $uploadPath)){
        JError::raiseWarning(500, 'Error moving file');

        return false;
    } else {
        //name the thumbnail image the same as the pdf file
        $pdfWithPath = $uploadPath;

        $thumbDirectory = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR
                        . '/components/com_ets_fast_track/assets/buildings/';

        $thumb = basename($filename, ".pdf");

        //add the desired extension to the thumbnail
        $thumb = $thumb.".jpg";

        $cmd="convert \"{$uploadPath}[0]\" -geometry 227x295 -density 222x294 -quality 100 -channel RGBA -bordercolor white -border 1x1 -fill none -draw matte 0,0 floodfill $thumbDirectory$thumb";

        exec($cmd);
    }
}
```

Comment: File permissions are correct?, do the user has write access on the folder? There is no code for the databes update process, so no clues there.

Comment: File permission is correct.

Comment: I am using joomla. Using its in built function i m saving the data.   code is below:         return parent::save($data);